# iOS Zoomview using Bubbleview touch location

Tags: ios, xcode

how to create bubble view for touch location ....(Xcode for iOS)
I had a problem with Zooming the image at certain location using bubbleview of touch location.
I wanna zoom certain location which I touch and that bubble have to display above my finger. But here it zooming upper location and bubble the upper location of my finger. How to zoom touch location and bubble it above my finger..?

```
UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject]; 
CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view]; 
if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.MeterView.frame, touchLocation)) { 
    _zoomView = [[BubbleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, touchLocation.y-120, 120,120)]; 
    [_zoomView setZoomScale:2.0];
}
```

Comment: UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if (CGRectContainsPoint(self.MeterView.frame, touchLocation)) {
   
        _zoomView = [[BubbleView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(3, touchLocation.y-120, 120,120)];

        [_zoomView setZoomScale:2.0];

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of very good projects on github which provides bubble zoom functionality where you move your finger.
They are,

1. [iOS-MagnifyingGlass](https://github.com/acoomans/iOS-MagnifyingGlass)
2. [BKZoomView](https://github.com/freshking/BKZoomView)

I hope it may help you.

Comment: those projects are doing the same which I created already. I need to zoom the point which I touch and the bubble should display above that point which mean above my finger.. Anyway thanks for your valuable reply friend.